# Regex pattern to exclude komma and dot

Tags: regex, angular, ionic2

I'm trying to build a Regex to exlude kommas and dots in an input (numbers only). I'm doing this in an Ionic 2 application which runs with Angular2 so I'm using the Angular 2 Validators.pattern.
I would pretend that the regex engine is the javascript one.

I read some Regex posts and build this pattern `[^,.]+` 
This works fine like it triggers if you type `1,2` but its not working for `1,`.

`1,` is still valid but i want it to be invalid just as 1,2. So how must I modify my pattern to fetch `x,x`, `x.x`  also as `x,` and `x.`?

Sorry if this question is a bit dumb but I never used Regex patterns befor and after trying it for 3 or 4 hours I surrendered...

Would be great if some of you could help me get that Regex working.

**EDIT:**

*in my TS File*

```
this._formValidator = new FormGroup({
        inputValidator: new FormControl('', Validators.maxLength(this._maxLength)),

        inputValidatorInteger: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
            Validators.pattern('[^,.]+')
        ]))
});
```

On Valuechange I'm mapping the errors to the right Error-Message and display them. Also tryed to log on any errors but there is no if I type `1,`. It's just invalid if I type something like `1,2`, even `1,,,,,` is not invalid. When I'm trying it with for example excluding 1 instead of exluding , its works like it should, `[^1]+`

*In My HTML file*

```
<ion-item class="listElement" [formGroup]="_formValidator">
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="_result.value" type="number" placeholder="Enter Something" formControlName="inputValidatorInteger"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

**EDIT 2:**
I need to use . Thats because I need the numerical keyboard to open on the smartphone which is achived with type="number".
Regex seems not to work with type="number" or rather its not working very well.

Comment: Just a test - add `^` and `$` anchors: `^[^,.]+$`

Comment: What do you mean by *fetch `x,x`, `x.x` also as `x,` and `x.`?*

Comment: Your pattern should work, see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/VKuGMI33OkSmvqnEqnCU?p=preview).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `^[^,.]+$` works like `[^,.]+` but thx anywaay for that suggestion

with fetch `x,x` i ment that it should be invalid if you wrote something like `1,1` and with `x,` i ment that it should be invalid if you wrote something like `3,` which is valid at the moment

Comment: Please share your code, from what I understand (and showed in the plunrkr above), your pattern should work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew added the Code snippets and some more infos.

Comment: isnt it better to check for the last letter and check if its , or . instead of regexing throughout the whole string ? just an idea

Comment: Change type="number" to "text". A regex validation will not fire for the input with type set to number.

Comment: Use * instead of +

Comment: @lastWhisper * instead of + doesent work seems like its just because its a type=number like WiktorStribiżew sayd. Seems like i just have to build my own validator

Comment: @DenkoMancheski i will do that in a custom validator. i was trying to move around that but seems like I need one

Thx at all :)

Comment: What do you mean by *have to build my own validator*? Is my comment answering your question?

Comment: Do you mean you need your input field to only allow integer input? Only digits `[0-9]`? Then use `'[0-9]+'` pattern with `type="text"`

Comment: See, without your clarification, weird answers start popping up.

Comment: I'm using it in my ionic2 app. That input needs to contain only numbers so I need to set the Input type="number" because in this case it opens a keyboard with numbers only on the smartphone. With that I don't need to check for other chars than numbers, I'm just in need to exlude commas and dots.

With using my own validator i ment something like explained [here](https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/ionic2-form-handling-and-validation#custom-validations). So i build my own validator and check if it contains komma or dot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129539/discussion-between-marvstar-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: A custom validator does not seem to work, if you succeed, please let me know.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew seems like comma and dot where ignored by validation.
When i log all validations i can see that komma is ignored until you type something not komma behind it  and dot sets the validation value to "" until you put something behind it
could this be a bug from the Angular2 Validation?

Comment: Sorry, I have not ever seen that. I still stand by my own suggestion: add onkeypress attribute.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've done a work around to get it working for now

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to verify that the input contains `,.` symbols. You can use this regex `[.,]`. It will match any string which contains at least one dot or comma [Example](https://regex101.com/r/yYXbW3/1). If the goal is to find any number which contains a comma or a dot, you might use something like similar to this

```
\d*[.,]\d*
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/yYXbW3/2)

Comment: @marvstar what is the difference between these 2 types? And what are you trying to achieve? Do you want to allow only numbers as user input? In this case `/^\d+$/`. If your numbers might contain dot between integer and fractional part `^\d+\.?\d*$`. If numbers might contain dot and a sign `^[+-]?\d+\.?\d*$`